# Tarjan's Algorithm Python Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, graph

I'm planning to use [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for a program in which I would be processing a file, converting the processed data to a dictionary, doing a topological sort on that dictionary (using this implementation), and then finding the longest path.

Is there any optimization that can be made to the below code, or can be be made more pythonic?

```
def strongly_connected_components(graph):

    index_counter = [0]
    stack = []; result = []
    lowlinks = {}; index = {}

    def tarjan(node):

        index[node] = index_counter[0]
        lowlinks[node] = index_counter[0]
        index_counter[0] += 1
        stack.append(node)

        try:
            successors = graph[node]
        except:
            successors = []
        for successor in successors:
            if successor not in lowlinks:
                tarjan(successor)
                lowlinks[node] = min(lowlinks[node],lowlinks[successor])
            elif successor in stack:
                lowlinks[node] = min(lowlinks[node],index[successor])

        if lowlinks[node] == index[node]:
            connected_component = []
            while True:
                successor = stack.pop()
                connected_component.append(successor)
                if successor == node: break
            component = tuple(connected_component)
            result.append(component)

    for node in graph:
        if node not in lowlinks:
            tarjan(node)

    return result
```

[Source](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh-files/blog/01208083168/tarjan.py)

The graph is unweighted, and would look something like this:-

```
test_graph = {
    'A' : ['B','S'],
    'B' : ['A'],
    'C' : ['D','E','F','S'],
    'D' : ['C'],
    'E' : ['C','H'],
    'F' : ['C','G'],
    'G' : ['F','S'],
    'H' : ['E','G'],
    'S' : ['A','C','G']
}
```

Comment: Do you know of [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/), which has [multiple functions to deal with strongly connected components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/component.html#strong-connectivity)? It also uses Tarjan's algorithm (with some modifications), so even if you don't want to use it you could have a look at their implementation.

Comment: It uses a modified Tarjan's implementation ("Uses Tarjan’s algorithm[1]_ with Nuutila’s modifications[2]_" - from the link). Also, I'm trying to avoid using any libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multi-statement lines

This:

```
stack = []; result = []
lowlinks = {}; index = {}
# ...
if successor == node: break
```

is generally discouraged; just use two lines.

### snake_case

This:

`lowlinks`

is usually spelled out, i.e. `low_links`.

### Bare `except`

```
    try:
        successors = graph[node]
    except:
        successors = []
```

has an except statement that's too broad. If you expect a `KeyError` from this, then `except KeyError`.